# Video Capture preview layout Must be square - like Android instagram ,Vine app

Tags: android, instagram, vine

I've seen instagram and vine app, the captured video preview size and play video size as same and square .
I've checked it has supported from Android version 4.0.

I've created camera preview  as http://pastebin.com/TvDn4eWt

but Proportions of video look a bit squeezed not like in instagram and vine app.

I've tried to change onmeasure width and height. but not use. the video look squeezed but its works on 2.3 version.

how to create video capture and play activity like in instagram and vine app. same size ?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure getting a reliably working app using Android's standard api is not possible for what you want. Using a video format that is not in the list of supported preview / supported video sizes will on many devices create the famous IllegalStateException when you start Android's MediaRecorder.

I checked Vine. They indeed can create videos in square format even on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3  7.1 which is like most of the modern Samsung devices quite sensible when it comes to setting the correct video parameters. Amazing!

I would assume that the Vine Android developers wrote their own version of the MediaRecorder and/or their own version of the surface holder for the preview and let these classes cut out a square from the video stream that comes from the camera.

If you want to try something like this: Good luck on your mission, you will have to do a deep dive into the sources of the Stagefreight framework which is a big bunch of C++ sources wrapped within a thin top layer of Java api classes. I would not recommend to try this.

Comment: This is wrong. You could quite easily use a frame layout with a weight of 0.5 (desired weight) to form square and then capture video from that view. @Nantoka keep it simple mate.

Comment: Hey @Jonny2Plates, do you have any links that we can read to help us create square videos?

Comment: @Migore adopted any solution?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar we ended embedding the ffmpeg library in our app and calling it in our app to crop the video.

Comment: @Migore any links where i can find some easy stuff to implement?

Comment: @Migore i tried this and its promising. However i am unable to make video size matching. I have created square Preview can u guide me how are setting Video Size

Comment: @Jonny2Plates, if the original posters question has a solution that can be "quite easily" implemented, why don't you post it here as an answer?

Comment: @Migore any help for square video capturing ? Thanks in advance :)